# jscoverage does not work without -g option

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

npm install jscoverage -g

What does the -g option do?
If I skip the -g option, jscoverage is not recognized as a valid command.

Comment: It installs the package globally (I.e., as a "system" command). Please [read the manual](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html#DESCRIPTION) first in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-g` flag tells npm to install it globally to your PATH. Without that, it would just be installed locally into your project folder.